# Chromium User Agent String on FreeBSD or OpenBSD

Tags: freebsd, chrome, openbsd, browser

I'm in need of a recent Chromium user agent string from a FreeBSD or OpenBSD desktop with the default user agent string.

I can only find Chrome useragent strings but no mention of Chromium. Other platforms have a distinction between Chrome and Chromium and I need to discern if Free and Open BSD behave in the same way or if it sends Chrome even when using Chromium ?

Thank you

Comment: Thank you Christopher. This is exactly what I needed. I'd be happy to accept it if you want to submit it as the anwser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the user agent string in Chromium does *not* include `Chromium`. This means that, to a server, there's no distinction between a user running Chrome and a user running Chromium (given the versions are the same).

However, distros compiling Chromium on their own can change what the default user agent string is. This is what Ubuntu does (at least).

For example, my user agent string is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/45.0.2438.3 Chrome/45.0.2438.3 Safari/537.36
```

Note that the `Chromium/45.0.2438.3` part was manually added by Ubuntu at compile-time. In addition, the `Ubuntu` was also manually added.

Comment: Thanks you for the information saiarcot895. I would upvote but I don't have the rep for it.

Answer (score -1):

There is no FreeBSD version of Google Chrome.

Comment: I know that but the user agent string mentioned in this thread https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=463848 is the same string as Chrome on other platforms. However Chromium on other platforms include Chromium in the string too in addition to Chrome.